# Why is my for-loop not accessing the arrays inside this object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, p5.js

I am trying to draw orange ellipses but the for-loop at the bottom of my code isn't drawing anything. I know the code below is the correct way to access arrays inside objects because I used it in another task and it worked. I previously had beginShape(); and endShape(); before and after my for-loop but that didn't work either.

Everything looks correct and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I would appreciate everyone's help. Thanks

```js
Case 601 - Cross Reference - stage 2

Fry is still on the loose. We think she’s resorted to stealing to get by.
Hopefully we can track her down by cross-referencing sightings and recent thefts in the area.

In the setup function, use a for loop to traverse the sightings, marking all of the locations on the map
where she was last seen. Do this by drawing small, DarkOrange stroke ellipses at each location.

In addition, we've assembled a list of recent thefts in the area. Using another for loop to traverse the
recent crime records, you should mark those locations on the map. Do this by drawing small, Magenta stroke rectangles centered over each location.

Use X11 colours. You can find a reference table at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors.

For this mission you will need ONLY the following:

- for loop
- stroke
- ellipse()

- stroke
- rect() NB. Draw each rectangle with the point at its center.


*/

var countyMap;

//Sightings of Casey Fry.

var absconder_record = {
    Loc_X: [639, 681, 712, 756, 715, 701, 753, 815, 795, 788, 781, 768, 750, 732, 714, 695, 693, 654, 624, 594, 555],
    Loc_Y: [288, 286, 293, 310, 368, 425, 436, 468, 506, 497, 486, 489, 500, 506, 514, 531, 552, 523, 500, 484, 474],
};

//Recent crime records.

var robbery_record = [ 
  { PointX : 403, PointY : 401},
  { PointX : 402, PointY : 360},
  { PointX : 427, PointY : 403},
  { PointX : 646, PointY : 284},
  { PointX : 639, PointY : 264},
  { PointX : 830, PointY : 434},
  { PointX : 809, PointY : 443},
  { PointX : 844, PointY : 496},
  { PointX : 802, PointY : 350},
  { PointX : 683, PointY : 413},
  { PointX : 552, PointY : 464},
  { PointX : 629, PointY : 498},
  { PointX : 712, PointY : 562},
  { PointX : 783, PointY : 603},
  { PointX : 415, PointY : 225},
  { PointX : 561, PointY : 282},
  { PointX : 562, PointY : 392},
  { PointX : 751, PointY : 283},
  { PointX : 680, PointY : 359},
  { PointX : 626, PointY : 436},
  { PointX : 701, PointY : 455},
  { PointX : 838, PointY : 565},
  { PointX : 322, PointY : 508},
  { PointX : 468, PointY : 556},
  { PointX : 625, PointY : 737} 
];


function preload()
{
    countyMap = loadImage("map.png")
}

function setup()
{
  createCanvas(countyMap.width, countyMap.height);

    image(countyMap, 0,0);

    //add your code below here
    stroke(255, 140, 0);
    
    for(i = 0; i <absconder_record.Loc_X[i].length; i++ ){
        ellipse(absconder_record.Loc_X[i], absconder_record.Loc_Y[i], 5)
    }
    
    
    


}
```

Here is the image its supposed to draw on:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this line:

```js
 for(i = 0; i <absconder_record.Loc_X[i].length; i++ ){
```

I think what you meant to do was:

`i <absconder_record.Loc_X.length`

---

> `i <absconder_record.Loc_X[i].length`

- `i` is 0
- `absconder_record.Loc_X[0]` is `639`
- `639` doesn't have a `length` property.

---

Follow up on the question in the comment:

> how do you loop through the array robbery_record?

A [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) takes 3 expressions:

1. an initializer, usually used to initialize a counter, as in `i = 0;`. (This runs only once, not on each iteration.)
2. a condition to test. if the condition is true, the body of the loop runs. the most common use is to see if the counter has exceeded some threshold, as in `i > 10`. if `i` is less than 10, run the body of the loop.
3. an expression that runs after each iteration of the loop. most commonly used to increment the counter: `i++`.

Taken together it looks like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  // body
}
```

1. `i` starts with a value of `0`.
2. The condition is evaluated: Is i less than 10?
3. If so, the body of the loop runs.
4. after the body runs, the last expression (`i++`) is executed. Now i is 1.
5. Repeat 2-4 until the condition isn't true any more (when i is no longer less than 10).

To use a for loop to iterate over an array, the common approach is to do exactly as above, but replace `10` with the length of the array. So in your case with robbery_record:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < robbery_record.length; i++) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Usually when someone's doing this it's because they want to execute the body once for each item in the array. Conveniently, because `i` gets incremented each time through the loop, you can get the current item inside the body of the loop via `robbery_record[i]`:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < robbery_record.length; i++) {
  const record = robbery_record[i];
  // do stuff with the current record
}
```

Each of your robbery_record entries is an object with `PointX` and `PointY` properties, so you can use those in the body of the loop:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < robbery_record.length; i++) {
  // record is an object, like: { PointX: 123, PointY: 456 }
  const record = robbery_record[i];

  // do stuff with the object's properties
  console.log(record.PointX) // 123
  console.log(record.PointY) // 456

  const x = record.PointX; // now x === 123
  const y = record.PointX; // now y === 456

  // etc.
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, if you don't mind me asking, how do you loop through the array robbery_record? I tried to understand other posts on here but I just got more confused. I'm not sure what to put in rect() for (j = 0; j < robbery_record.length; j++){
        rect()
        }

Comment: Rather than use a for loop you might consider using [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), as in `robbery_record.forEach(record => { ... })`. Inside the function you'll have access to `record.PointX` and `record.PointY`. If you're determined to use a for loop for some reason let me know and I can clarify that.

Comment: I just saw you've got explicit instructions to use a for loop. Sec.

Comment: Updated my answer with some detailed info on the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at `i <absconder_record.Loc_X[i].length`,

- `absconder_record.Loc_X` is an array
- `absconder_record.Loc_X[i]` is a number
- `absconder_record.Loc_X[i].length` is the `length` property of a number (cooerced to a Number object) which is `undefined`
- A comparison check for a number being less than `undefined` returns `false`

So the loop condition always fails and the loop body never executes.